# Follow an array based on the variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to get my client to know which array it should follow.

```
var json = [{
  command: "command 1", 
  giveRole: "884005303811702794"
}, {
  command: "command 2", 
  giveRole : "948609651673563179"
  }];
```

```
  for (var key in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(json[key].command);
      console.log(json[key].giveRole);
    }
  }
```

```
  client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(json[key].command)) {
      target.roles.add([json[key].giveRole]);
    }
  });
```

For example if I send "command 1" it should give role "884005303811702794" not "948609651673563179".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to look it up. You can use find to do it.

```js
var json = [{
  command: "command 1",
  giveRole: "884005303811702794"
}, {
  command: "command 2",
  giveRole: "948609651673563179"
}];


function getCommand (command) {
  return json.find(function (item) {
    return item.command === command;
  });
}

console.log("command 1", getCommand("command 1"));
console.log("command 2", getCommand("command 2"));
console.log("command 3", getCommand("command 3"));
```

Other option is change your commands so it is an object instead of an array.

```js
var myCommands = {
  "command 1": {
    giveRole: "884005303811702794"
  },
  "command 2": {
    giveRole: "948609651673563179"
  },
};


function getCommand(command) {
  return myCommands[command] || null;
}

console.log("command 1", getCommand("command 1"));
console.log("command 2", getCommand("command 2"));
console.log("command 3", getCommand("command 3"));
```

And if the command is not the whole string, you can loop

```js
var json = [{
  command: "command 1",
  giveRole: "884005303811702794"
}, {
  command: "command 2",
  giveRole: "948609651673563179"
}];


function getCommand (command) {
  return json.find(function (item) {
    return command.toLowerCase().startsWith(item.command);
  });
}

console.log("command 1", getCommand("command 1 eat pizza"));
console.log("command 2", getCommand("command 2 drink water"));
console.log("command 3", getCommand("command 3 dance"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you seem to try to find the element in your array by using a key, but your array is not keyed.

In Javascript, you can use the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method on arrays. This will return the first element on the array that returns a true value.

As per the example of the Doc, you should be able to find the valid command in with this :

```
let json = [{
  command: "command 1", 
  giveRole: "884005303811702794"
}, {
  command: "command 2", 
  giveRole : "948609651673563179"
}];

const command = json.find(element => element.command === 'command 1');
```

Another good way to store your commands would be to store it in an object / associative arrays. Ex:

```js
const commands = {
  command1: '884005303811702794',
  command2: '948609651673563179',
}

console.log('command1', commands['command1'])
console.log('command2', commands['command2'])
```

That way, you could simply use the value of the command to have the role that you want.

In your situation, it seems like you want a discord bot to give a role when a message starts with "command 1" or "command 2". If you implement a keyed array, it would look something like this :

```
const commands = {
  command1: '884005303811702794',
  command2: '948609651673563179',
}

client.on('message', message => {
  if (commands.hasOwnProperty(message.content)) {
     target.roles.add(commands[message.content]);
  }
});
```